# tf.GradientTape gradient() returns None

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, gradienttape

I am trying to train my keras model using TensorFlow, so far I can build the model,

```
def Model(input_shape, num_of_layers):
    num_of_layers = 5
    mod = keras.models.Sequential()
    mod.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape = (input_shape,)))
    for i in range(num_of_layers - 1):
        mod.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'tanh'))
    mod.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'tanh'))
    return mod
```

and loss function.

```
def loss(u_pred, u_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(u_pred, u_true))
```

Then I create a `train` function to train the model.

```
def train(model, X, epoch = 500, lr = 1e-3):
    trainable_params = [tf.Variable(model.get_weights()[i]) for i in range(len(model.get_weights()))]
    loss_array = []
    optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr)
    for i in range(epoch):
        with tf.GradientTape() as g:
            g.watch(trainable_params)
            loss_val = loss(model(X), tf.zeros_like(X))
        grad = g.gradient(loss_val, trainable_params)
    ...
```

The `grad` returns a vector of None when I print it. What went wrong with my `train` function? I have converted my model's weights and biases to tensor object using `tf.Variable`. Using `tf.cast` or `tf.convert_to_tensor` doesn't help either.

Comment: Why do you create a completely new set of variables instead of just using `model.trainable_variables`?

Comment: You don't have to "convert" your model weights to tensor, where did you get this idea? See the comment by @xdurch0

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy, the reason I converted the weights and biases to tensor is because when I trained them without converting to Tensor first it returned error because I fed a numpy.ndarray object. Also thanks to xdurch0 I might consider using it instead of model.get_weights()

Comment: That is not the right approach, this seems to be a XY problem, you are asking of what you think the solution is, instead of asking about the actual problem.